# Why does querying date data type in SQL Server as work yyyymmdd instead of yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just like the title says. My professor marked points off of all my queries because I queried date data type in this format: `yyyymmdd`. Example; Date between `yyyymmdd`. Instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I just want to know if there is any argument I can make for the points because it seems pretty trivial since the query still worked.

Comment: This is just an opinion,but I would say your prof is wrong, if you look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the date format 112 is the `ISO` format exactly as you used. Type 23 is the format your prof used, being `ISO8601` but IMO they are both perfectly OK unless there was something else in the question which you haven't showed us.

Answer (score 6):

A good argument against using `yyyy-mm-dd` (with no time) is that, depending on language/DMY settings<sup>1</sup>, SQL Server can get it wrong, resulting in incorrect queries<sup>2</sup> or errors:

```
set language british

select * from sys.objects where create_date between '2001-05-01' and '2001-05-30'
```

Produces the error

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

This is because, for whatever reason, SQL Server thinks that the british use `yyyy-dd-mm` (We do not).

`yyyymmdd` is *unamibiguously* interpreted by SQL Server no matter what language settings are in force.

Note that this is SQL Server specific.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that I explicitly change a setting in this script but even without it, some user's *default* settings may cause the same issue.

<sup>2</sup>Such as Suraj Kumar's example from the comments:

```
select * from sys.objects where create_date between '2001-05-01' and '2001-05-11'
```

Which queries between 5th January and 5th November, not between 1st May and the 11th.

Comment: Wow, I would never have known that SQL Server gets that format wrong!

Comment: If only SQL Server would finally support ISO date literals as most other DBMS do

Comment: Any reason `select * from sys.objects where create_date between '2001-05-01' and '2001-05-11'` do not give an error?

Comment: @SurajKumar - because now you're querying for things between 5th January and 5th November. Like I said, *incorrect* queries are the other outcome if you don't get errors

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In this way, we can say it matches with the both the data and the format while getting the result.

Comment: note: the error is very "subtle" .... applicable only to datetime(!?) :
`set language british;
select month('2001-05-11'),day('2001-05-11');
select month(cast('2001-05-11' as datetime)),day(cast('2001-05-11' as datetime));  
select month(cast('2001-05-11' as date)),day(cast('2001-05-11' as date));  
select month(cast('2001-05-11' as datetime2)),day(cast('2001-05-11' as datetime2));`

Comment: does this apply even when the metadata of the table has the date variable formatted as yyyy-mm-dd? I guess my prof said that it is because it doesn't match the date format of the specific database/table.

Comment: If the table is storing dates, it *ought* to be storing those in `date` or `datetime`/`datetime2` columns. Be clear here - those types don't *have* a format